# How to append an input inside each div that created from Json

Tags: javascript, json

i have a json and i create a simple dynamic form based on my json file . there are labels and each lables are exist in divs seperately.but there is a problem in this code that this code does not show my inputs. how to appends them inside each divs below each lable?

this code should show input but does not work.

here is my code :

```js
document.body.onload = addElement;

function addElement() {
  var schema = [{
      "queestion": "Name",
      "type": "128",
      "attrs": [{
          "attr": {
            "name": "class",
            "value": "nofilling2 engword"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "id",
            "value": "name"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "type",
            "value": "text"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "placeholder",
            "value": "Name"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "_root.passengerinfo__1.passengerinfo.fullname.firstname"
          }
        }
      ]

    },
    {
      "queestion": "Family",
      "type": "128",
      "attrs": [{
          "attr": {
            "name": "class",
            "value": "nofilling2 engword"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "id",
            "value": "family"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "type",
            "value": "text"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "placeholder",
            "value": "Family"
          }
        },
        {
          "attr": {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "_root.passengerinfo__1.passengerinfo.fullname.lastname"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  for (var i = 0; i < schema.length; i++) {
    var type = schema[i].type;
    if (type == 128) {

      var titleinput = schema[i].queestion;

      var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.className = 'c-infoo';

      var newContent = document.createElement('label');
      newContent.className = 'abs-tlt';

      newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
      newContent.innerHTML = titleinput + " : ";
      document.getElementById('tblreserve').appendChild(newDiv);

      var string = "<input ";
      for (var y = 0; y < schema[i].attrs.length; y++) {
        string += schema[i].attrs[y].attr.name + '="' + schema[i].attrs[y].attr.value + '" '
      }
      string += ">";
      newDiv.appendChild = string;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tblreserve"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last line you wrote `newDiv.appendChild=string;`.

But `string`as its name says is a String and can't be appended as an child.

You can use your `string` by writing `newDiv.innerHTML+=string;` instead.

**PS:** Please fix your indentation style. It doesn't look very nice...